# Is it possible to Host ASP.Net Core MVC Website in cPanel?

Tags: asp.net-core, hosting, cpanel

I need to Host my Asp.net core MVC website in cPanle.Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can. Which cPanel are you using?

Comment: https://node231.registerlk.com:2083/